# Setting the Camera to Perspective From Orthographic causing Camera to change direction

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am attempting to develop an extension for the autodesk forge viewer api similar in functionality to the current first person navigation tool included. The issue I'm describing also appears with the first person navigation tool, so I'll be using that to illustrate my example here.

Orthographic image of the building. 
[Image of model after load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46gz1.png)

Now Navigate using the mouse to a spot like the following. This is done by clicking the mouse to rotate the model and mousewheel to scroll in.
[Image of model after navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4GJn.png)

Clicking the first person view button has moved the camera view inside the building, to a place a little distance up. 
[Image of inside building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBHJr.png)

This does not appear to change the position or target values of the camera, and happens even if the camera is locked. The actual call that makes the move seems to be the call to navigation.toPerspective.

What I'd like is to know if anyone knows of a workaround that would allow me to use the first person from the place that the camera was focused on. As I said before, the plugin I am writing isn't actually the first person extension, so assume I can make any changes necessary at the points they need to be made.

Answer (score 0):

If you dig into the source code (can do so via [source map](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/) to `\extensions\BimWalk\BimWalk.js`) of the built-in First Person extension then during `activation` the following navigation would occur (as this is done programmatically it won't respect the camera lock):

```
viewer.navigation.toPerspective(); //Switch to perspective (view or real world as opposed to orthography) camera
viewer.navigation.setVerticalFov(75, true); //This sets the vertical field of view to 75 degree for a better "walking" experience
//It also records the current vertical fov and sets it back when exiting First Person
```

And then when quitting First Person it sets the vertical field of view back.

```
viewer.navigation.setVerticalFov(_previousFov, true);
```

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I'm aware that the perspective and FOV are being changed as part of the activate, I'm asking why the change to a perspective camera changes what the camera is looking at, and, more importantly, whether there's a way of preventing it from doing this (if I hypothetically had full control of the BIMWalk.js code),

Comment: You can check on the source code to find out what exactly is happening under the hood with `toPerspective()` which is at line 60108 of viewer3d.min.js with source map enabled. And to disable it one hacky but effective way would be to piggyback it with something like `viewer.getCamera().toPerspective = function(){ this.isPerspective=true; //adapt the navigation to your own needs here}` but be sure to save a copy of the original function and restore it later once you are done.